# How to install Maxima and make syntax on Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: command-line, server, 18.04, software-installation, syntax

How to install Maxima computer algebra system, and make a syntax like the screenshot that is shown below? What is a similar application to Maxima that can run from the command-line in Ubuntu Server 18.04?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Maxima is a version of the MIT-developed MACSYMA system, modified to run under Common Lisp. It is an interactive expert system and programming environment for symbolic and numerical mathematical manipulation. Written in Lisp, it allows differentiation, integration, solution of linear or polynomial equations, factoring of polynomials, expansion of functions in Laurent or Taylor series, computation of Poisson series, matrix and tensor manipulations, and two- and three-dimensional  graphics. Procedures may be written using an ALGOL-like syntax, and both Lisp-like functions and pattern matching facilities are  provided. Files  containing  Maxima  objects may be read from and written to disk files. Pre-written Maxima commands may be read from a file and executed, allowing batch-mode use.

*wxmaxima* is a GUI for the Maxima computer algebra system.

To install *maxima* command-line program in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install maxima
```

```
$ maxima

Maxima 5.41.0 http://maxima.sourceforge.net
using Lisp GNU Common Lisp (GCL) GCL 2.6.12
Distributed under the GNU Public License. 
(%i1) fpprec:1500000$

(%i2) bfloat(sqrt(2))$
time
(%i3) time(%);
(%o3)                                [7.1]
(%i4)
```

Here is the same input solved in wxMaxima GUI application.

[image]
<sup>**The syntax highlighting in the center pane is explained [here](http://www.hippasus.com/resources/symmath/maximasym.html)**</sup>

Content of the content.xml file which was created by wxMaxima is shown below. This file can be accessed by renaming the saved file from wxMaxima from untitled.wxmx to untitled.zip, and then extracting the content.xml file from the .zip archive.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--   Created by wxMaxima 18.02.0   -->
<!--https://andrejv.github.io/wxmaxima/-->

<wxMaximaDocument version="1.5" zoom="100" activecell="1">

<cell type="code">
<input>
<editor type="input">
<line>fpprec:1500000$</line>
<line>bfloat(sqrt(2))$</line>
<line>time(%);</line>
<line></line>
</editor>
</input>
<output>
<mth><lbl>(%o3) </lbl><t>[</t><n>7.05</n><t>]</t>
</mth></output>
</cell>

</wxMaximaDocument>
```

Comment: @JohanKunRiyanto The input lines in coba.mac are saved by wxMaxima (*File* -> *Save*) in a file named content.xml. Each line is enclosed by a pair of XML `<line>` and `</line>` tags. How to extract the input lines in coba.mac from content.xml and write them somewhere else using a bash script is *too broad* to include in this question. It should be asked as a separate question instead.

Comment: can it be used for the PHP script to send the maxima script above ?

Comment: Yes, that can be done with a PHP script, but writing the PHP script is out of scope for Ask Ubuntu. If you've got your own PHP code, you can ask for help debugging it at Stack Overflow Q&A, but you have to show your code.